# Hibernate Sequence Generator requests 2 values

Tags: java, sql, spring, postgresql, hibernate

I have found a strange case about Hibernate Sequence Generator. When I save the entity with repository Hibernate performs two queries.

```sql
select nextval ('some_sequence')
select nextval ('some_sequence')
```

Is is some Hibernate pre-caching behavior? Can it be tuned?

Here is the entity:

```java
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@Table(name = "host_black_list")
public class RestrictedHost {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(
        strategy = SEQUENCE,
        generator = "restricted_host_generator"
    )
    @SequenceGenerator(
        name = "restricted_host_generator",
        sequenceName = "some_sequence"
    )
    @Column(name = "host_black_list_id")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "host_name")
    @NotNull
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "msisdn_count")
    @NotNull
    private long msisdnCount;
}
```

And here is the test code:

```java
final var id = transactionTemplate.execute(status -> {
    RestrictedHost restrictedHost = new RestrictedHost();
    restrictedHost.setName("some_name");
    restrictedHost.setMsisdnCount(156);
    final var host = restrictedHostRepository.saveAndFlush(restrictedHost);
    return host.getId();
});
```

I use Testcontainers + PostgreSQL 9.6.8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes hibernate default way cache seq values.

Default cached values are 50. But I didn't think it run one seq query twice.

persistence.xml:
this settings said old style or new style seq usage

```
<property name="hibernate.id.new_generator_mappings" value="false"/>
```

If you use GenericGenerator, then it works without cache, so all persist fetch a seq value!

```
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "some_seq_generator")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "some_seq_generator", strategy = "sequence", parameters = { @Parameter(name = "sequence", value = "some_seq") })
```